# Add login page to existing angularjs metronic theme

Tags: html, angularjs, metronic

I am using metronic angularjs theme for creating a web app. But that theme doesn't have a login page and I want to create one for user login through facebook and normal login.

I was wondering how can I add a login page to an existing theme as I am new to angularjs.

I have tried creating a login master file at the same path where index file exists but I think I am doing something wrong.

This theme is using index file as a core for all the views and hence have header, footer and sidebar defined in the same for all the html files but I don't want to use index file as core for login page as we don't header and all for login screen.

**index.html code:-**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="MetronicApp">
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head>
<title data-ng-bind="'abc | ' + $state.current.data.pageTitle"></title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<meta content="" name="description"/>
<meta content="" name="author"/>
<!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../../assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../../assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../../assets/global/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
<!-- BEGIN DYMANICLY LOADED CSS FILES(all plugin and page related styles must be loaded between GLOBAL and THEME css files ) -->
<link id="ng_load_plugins_before"/>
<!-- END DYMANICLY LOADED CSS FILES -->
<!-- BEGIN THEME STYLES -->
<!-- DOC: To use 'rounded corners' style just load 'components-rounded.css' stylesheet instead of 'components.css' in the below style tag -->
<link href="../../../assets/global/css/components.css" id="style_components" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../../assets/global/css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../../assets/admin/layout2/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../../assets/admin/layout2/css/themes/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color"/>
<link href="../../../assets/admin/layout2/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- END THEME STYLES -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
</head>
<!-- END HEAD -->
<!-- BEGIN BODY -->
<body ng-controller="AppController" class="page-boxed page-header-fixed page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo page-container-bg-solid page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo page-on-load" ng-class="{'page-sidebar-closed': settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed}">
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE SPINNER -->
    <div ng-spinner-bar class="page-spinner-bar">
        <div class="bounce1"></div>
        <div class="bounce2"></div>
        <div class="bounce3"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE SPINNER -->

    <!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
    <div data-ng-include="'tpl/header.html'" data-ng-controller="HeaderController" class="page-header navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    </div>
    <!-- END HEADER -->

    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>

    <!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-container">
            <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
            <div data-ng-include="'tpl/sidebar.html'" data-ng-controller="SidebarController" class="page-sidebar-wrapper">          
            </div>
            <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
            <div class="page-content-wrapper">
                <div class="page-content">
                    <!-- BEGIN STYLE CUSTOMIZER(optional) -->
                    <div data-ng-include="'tpl/theme-panel.html'" data-ng-controller="ThemePanelController" class="theme-panel hidden-xs hidden-sm">                
                    </div>
                    <!-- END STYLE CUSTOMIZER -->
                    <!-- BEGIN ACTUAL CONTENT -->
                    <div ui-view class="fade-in-up">
                    </div> 
                    <!-- END ACTUAL CONTENT -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
        <div data-ng-include="'tpl/footer.html'" data-ng-controller="FooterController" class="page-footer">
        </div>
        <!-- END FOOTER -->
    </div>
    <!-- END CONTAINER -->

    <!-- BEGIN JAVASCRIPTS(Load javascripts at bottom, this will reduce page load time) -->

    <!-- BEGIN CORE JQUERY PLUGINS -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/excanvas.min.js"></script> 
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/jquery.cokie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END CORE JQUERY PLUGINS -->

    <!-- BEGIN CORE ANGULARJS PLUGINS -->
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular-sanitize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular-touch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ocLazyLoad.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END CORE ANGULARJS PLUGINS -->

    <!-- BEGIN APP LEVEL ANGULARJS SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END APP LEVEL ANGULARJS SCRIPTS -->

    <!-- BEGIN APP LEVEL JQUERY SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="../../../assets/global/scripts/metronic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../assets/admin/layout2/scripts/layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../assets/admin/layout2/scripts/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <!-- END APP LEVEL JQUERY SCRIPTS -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* Init Metronic's core jquery plugins and layout scripts */
        $(document).ready(function() {   
            Metronic.init(); // Run metronic theme
            Metronic.setAssetsPath('../../../assets/'); // Set the assets folder path           
        });
    </script>
    <!-- END JAVASCRIPTS -->
</body>
<!-- END BODY -->
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var MetronicApp = angular.module("MetronicApp", [
    "ui.router", 
    "ui.bootstrap", 
    "oc.lazyLoad",  
    "ngSanitize"
]); 

MetronicApp.config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', function($ocLazyLoadProvider) {
    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({

    });
}]);



MetronicApp.config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);



MetronicApp.factory('settings', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    var settings = {
        layout: {
            pageSidebarClosed: false, // sidebar state
            pageAutoScrollOnLoad: 1000 // auto scroll to top on page load
        },
        layoutImgPath: Metronic.getAssetsPath() + 'admin/layout/img/',
        layoutCssPath: Metronic.getAssetsPath() + 'admin/layout/css/'
    };

    $rootScope.settings = settings;

    return settings;
}]);


MetronicApp.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        Metronic.initComponents(); 
    });
}]);


MetronicApp.controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
        Layout.initHeader(); // init header
    });
}]);

MetronicApp.controller('SidebarController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
        Layout.initSidebar(); // init sidebar
    });
}]);

MetronicApp.controller('ThemePanelController', ['$scope', function($scope) {    
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
        Demo.init(); // init theme panel
    });
}]);


MetronicApp.controller('FooterController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
        Layout.initFooter(); // init footer
    });
}]);


MetronicApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // Redirect any unmatched url
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard.html");

    $stateProvider


        // Dashboard
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard.html",
            templateUrl: "views/dashboard.html",            
            data: {pageTitle: 'Admin Dashboard Template'},
            controller: "DashboardController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before a LINK element with this ID. Dynamic CSS files must be loaded between core and theme css files
                        files: [
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/morris/morris.css',
                            '../../../assets/admin/pages/css/tasks.css',

                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/morris/morris.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/morris/raphael-min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/jquery.sparkline.min.js',

                            '../../../assets/admin/pages/scripts/index3.js',
                            '../../../assets/admin/pages/scripts/tasks.js',

                             'js/controllers/DashboardController.js'
                        ] 
                    });
                }]
            }
        })

        // AngularJS plugins
        .state('fileupload', {
            url: "/file_upload.html",
            templateUrl: "views/file_upload.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'AngularJS File Upload'},
            controller: "GeneralPageController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                        name: 'angularFileUpload',
                        files: [
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min.js',
                        ] 
                    }, {
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        files: [
                            'js/controllers/GeneralPageController.js'
                        ]
                    }]);
                }]
            }
        })

        // UI Select
        .state('uiselect', {
            url: "/ui_select.html",
            templateUrl: "views/ui_select.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'AngularJS Ui Select'},
            controller: "UISelectController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                        name: 'ui.select',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before',
                        files: [
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-select/select.min.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-select/select.min.js'
                        ] 
                    }, {
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        files: [
                            'js/controllers/UISelectController.js'
                        ] 
                    }]);
                }]
            }
        })

        // UI Bootstrap
        .state('uibootstrap', {
            url: "/ui_bootstrap.html",
            templateUrl: "views/ui_bootstrap.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'AngularJS UI Bootstrap'},
            controller: "GeneralPageController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        files: [
                            'js/controllers/GeneralPageController.js'
                        ] 
                    }]);
                }] 
            }
        })

        // Tree View
        .state('tree', {
            url: "/tree",
            templateUrl: "views/tree.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'jQuery Tree View'},
            controller: "GeneralPageController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                        files: [
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css',

                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/jstree/dist/jstree.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/admin/pages/scripts/ui-tree.js',
                            'js/controllers/GeneralPageController.js'
                        ] 
                    }]);
                }] 
            }
        })     

        // Form Tools
        .state('formtools', {
            url: "/form-tools",
            templateUrl: "views/form_tools.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'Form Tools'},
            controller: "GeneralPageController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                        files: [
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-fileinput/bootstrap-fileinput.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/jquery-tags-input/jquery.tagsinput.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-markdown/css/bootstrap-markdown.min.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/typeahead/typeahead.css',

                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/fuelux/js/spinner.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-fileinput/bootstrap-fileinput.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/jquery-inputmask/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/jquery.input-ip-address-control-1.0.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-pwstrength/pwstrength-bootstrap.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/jquery-tags-input/jquery.tagsinput.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-maxlength/bootstrap-maxlength.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-touchspin/bootstrap.touchspin.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/typeahead/handlebars.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/admin/pages/scripts/components-form-tools.js',

                            'js/controllers/GeneralPageController.js'
                        ] 
                    }]);
                }] 
            }
        })        

        // Date & Time Pickers
        .state('pickers', {
            url: "/pickers",
            templateUrl: "views/pickers.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'Date & Time Pickers'},
            controller: "GeneralPageController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before',
                        files: [
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/clockface/css/clockface.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css',

                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/clockface/js/clockface.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/moment.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js',

                            '../../../assets/admin/pages/scripts/components-pickers.js',

                            'js/controllers/GeneralPageController.js'
                        ] 
                    }]);
                }] 
            }
        })

        // Custom Dropdowns
        .state('dropdowns', {
            url: "/dropdowns",
            templateUrl: "views/dropdowns.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'Custom Dropdowns'},
            controller: "GeneralPageController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before',
                        files: [
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/jquery-multi-select/css/multi-select.css',

                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/jquery-multi-select/js/jquery.multi-select.js',

                            '../../../assets/admin/pages/scripts/components-dropdowns.js',

                            'js/controllers/GeneralPageController.js'
                        ] 
                    }]);
                }] 
            }
        }) 

        // Advanced Datatables
        .state('datatablesAdvanced', {
            url: "/datatables/advanced.html",
            templateUrl: "views/datatables/advanced.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'Advanced Datatables'},
            controller: "GeneralPageController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                        files: [
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.css',                             
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.css', 
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/Scroller/css/dataTables.scroller.min.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/ColReorder/css/dataTables.colReorder.min.css',

                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/all.min.js',
                            'js/scripts/table-advanced.js',

                            'js/controllers/GeneralPageController.js'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        })

        // Ajax Datetables
        .state('datatablesAjax', {
            url: "/datatables/ajax.html",
            templateUrl: "views/datatables/ajax.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'Ajax Datatables'},
            controller: "GeneralPageController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                        files: [
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.css',                             
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.css',

                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/all.min.js',

                            '../../../assets/global/scripts/datatable.js',
                            'js/scripts/table-ajax.js',

                            'js/controllers/GeneralPageController.js'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        })

        // User Profile
        .state("profile", {
            url: "/profile",
            templateUrl: "views/profile/main.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'User Profile'},
            controller: "UserProfileController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'MetronicApp',  
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                        files: [
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-fileinput/bootstrap-fileinput.css',
                            '../../../assets/admin/pages/css/profile.css',
                            '../../../assets/admin/pages/css/tasks.css',

                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/jquery.sparkline.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-fileinput/bootstrap-fileinput.js',

                            '../../../assets/admin/pages/scripts/profile.js',

                            'js/controllers/UserProfileController.js'
                        ]                    
                    });
                }]
            }
        })

        // User Profile Dashboard
        .state("profile.dashboard", {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: "views/profile/dashboard.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'User Profile'}
        })

        // User Profile Account
        .state("profile.account", {
            url: "/account",
            templateUrl: "views/profile/account.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'User Account'}
        })

        // User Profile Help
        .state("profile.help", {
            url: "/help",
            templateUrl: "views/profile/help.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'User Help'}      
        })

        // Todo
        .state('todo', {
            url: "/todo",
            templateUrl: "views/todo.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'Todo'},
            controller: "TodoController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({ 
                        name: 'MetronicApp',  
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                        files: [
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.css',
                            '../../../assets/admin/pages/css/todo.css',

                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js',
                            '../../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.min.js',

                            '../../../assets/admin/pages/scripts/todo.js',

                            'js/controllers/TodoController.js'  
                        ]                    
                    });
                }]
            }
        })

}]);


MetronicApp.run(["$rootScope", "settings", "$state", function($rootScope, settings, $state) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state; // state to be accessed from view
}]);
```

It would be great if someone can help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduction:

Unfortunately almost every theme bought on internet should be "ready to use" but in reality are filled of jquery plugins and needs to be organized with a different architecture: managing dependencies with bower/npm, have good gulp scripts to manage most used tasks, removing all jquery code from controllers, substituting jquery dependencies with angular dependencies and removing all components that you will not use.

Answer:

No, you don't need a "login master file" (or index.html and login.html) if you well organize the routes. Angular is a Single Page Application framework and not a Two Page Application :)

Usually I use the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and I prefere organize states in two main groups `public` and `private` and then I create many child states of them:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('public', {
    abstract: true,
    template: "<ui-view/>"
  })
  .state('public.site', {
    url: '/site',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: 'SiteCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'site/_site.html'
  })
  .state('public.site.home', {
    url: '/',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'home/_home.html'
  })
  .state('public.site.product', {
    url: '/products',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: 'ProductCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'product/_product.html'
  })
  .state('public.login', {
    url: '/login',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'login/_login.html'
  });

$stateProvider
  .state('private', {
    abstract: true,
    template: "<ui-view/>"
  })
  .state('private.admin', {
    url: '/admin',
    controllerAs: 'admin',
    controller: 'AdminCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'admin/_admin.html'
  })
  .state('private.admin.category', {
    url: '/categories',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: 'CategoryCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'category/_category.html'
  })
  .state('private.admin.product', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/products',
    template: '<ui-view/>'
  })
  .state('private.admin.product.list', {
    url: '/',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: 'ProductListCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'product/_product.list.html'
  })
  .state('private.admin.product.edit', {
    url: '/edit/{id}',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: 'ProductEditCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'product/_product.edit.html'
  });
```

The states `public.site` and `private.admin` are important because are the parent of all `public` or `private` routes. Will be the parent layout where I place the header, menu, navigation, footer etc. For example my _admin.html is look like:

```
<div id="header">
  HEADER ADMIN
</div>
<aside id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="private.admin.category">Categories</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="private.admin.product.list">Products</a>
    </li>
    ...
    ...
  </ul>
</aside>
<div ui-view class="content">
  <!-- admin child states will be injected here -->

</div>
```

Generally the login page has a different layout of the site or the admin panel. There are no header, site menu, no navigation etc.. only there is a login form. For this reason the login state `public.login` is not a child of `public.site`.

And finally I show you my index.html. Is a clean/empty body html with no html code:

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title page-title>Default Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/of/styles/abcd.css" />
    <!-- all css files included here -->
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <div ui-view>
      <!-- all states will be injected here -->
    </div>

    <script src="path/of/scripts/bcds.js"></script>
    <!-- all js files included here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

[Originally answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31231967/1375596)

Comment: okay so according to you I should make two states if I want to use two files as master?

Comment: No, you don't need two "master" (or index.html) if you well organize the routes. Angular is a Single Page Application framework and not a Two Page Application :)

Comment: oh okay. So I just need to define the states and it will work. Let me try it and I'll get back to you if i'll face any issue :)

Comment: You need to refactor your index.html and put header, footer of admin in the _admin.html. Follow exactly the code that I showed you

Comment: Yeah its done and redirecting to login page also but now the header is removed from all the views. All the views are fetching the details from index file :(

Comment: Thank you so much bro, I was searching this since two weeks. Thank you