# How to separate admin and the front web in angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm going to build a full project using angular 2, the project contains admin panel and a front-end web for users.

I don't know how to separate admin from the web, should I use routing for this? But this will require me to import all components inside the `app.module.ts` or there is another way to use two `app.module.ts` one for the web and one for the admin?

Or what should I do?

Comment: are you looking for role based application?

Comment: the admin is completely different from the web

Comment: Then just build a completely different web app.

Comment: Elaborate the completely different one

Comment: i don't know what is the best for this situation, its a video website like YouTube, should i make admin panel or just make one project with one ui and using ACL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've built this recently and what I did was simply to split the routes into two different modules.

So you'd have this:

```
- +admin
  - routes
    - +dashboard
    - +login
    - ... etc
- +website
  - routes
    - +home
    - +profile
    - ... etc
```

Then what you want to do is use a `canLoad` guard to prevent modules from being loaded if you are not authorised to do so. This will protect the admin area in the frontend so that the code isn't exposed unless you're an admin with that privilege.

This is the easiest way of doing it if you don't want to split the project into two smaller projects. Which I wouldn't do personally since sharing things across the apps becomes more complicated.

**EDIT:**

The routing would look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/+website/website.module#WebsiteModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: 'app/+admin-area/admin-area.module#AdminAreaModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
    AppComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})

export class AppRouterModule {}
```

So simply going to `/admin` would load the admin area module, which would have another router module looking something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminAreaComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: 'app/+admin-area/pages/+login/login.module#LoginModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: 'app/+admin-area/pages/+dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
        canLoad: [AuthGuardService]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ComponentsModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    AdminAreaComponent
  ]
})

export class AdminAreaRouterModule {}
```

Here you can see that `/admin/dashboard` is protected by a guard which checks the user's role.

Comment: how can you change modules using routing? can you explain how did you do that?

Comment: @MoustafaElkady Updated answer.

Comment: why did you make dashboard & login as a modules not components

Comment: Because every page should be a module. It's best practice and also allows you to lazy load modules which I've done here.

Comment: can you add the full content of website.module && login.module because i don't know how it will be

Comment: and would i make login.module and login.component ? can you provide me full example of full article showing that

Comment: And what about index.html file? for instance I have different titles, imports, meta tags both in admin and client? how do I  separate them?

Comment: @Gh111 For admin you shouldn't have to worry about metatags since I don't think you want any crawlers to index those pages. As for the title you can just use the built in metadata service that angular provides. Not sure what you mean with imports.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Thanks, I didn't know that BrowserModule lets us do stuff like that, but now everything is clear to me.

Comment: Hi,
I have done the same for admin and website and route is working fine for both module, but how can I split css and js for both modules. as I have used 2 separate themes for admin and website module. I'm using Angular 6.

Comment: @DevRamesh You can do that using the `ng generate` command to create a workspace project, that contains 2 subprojects along with a library for shared things.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz So are these modules lazy loaded. In my case I would not even want the admin specific JS files to be in the deployed bundle. From your example, I am not sure if that will work